# Pandas sum column with scalar results in zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I am summing a column of a `pandas` dataframe with a scalar and the result is a column full of zeros. The weird thing is that sometimes it will return zeros and sometimes it won't. If someone would tell me this I wouldn't believe it, that's why I a made a video showing this result:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15853805/pandas%20bug.mp4

Can someone explain me this black magic? I am loosing my trust on `pandas` and I really need it to work.

Ok with this code I can get a similar error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pdb import set_trace as pdb

for _ in xrange(100):
    data = np.random.randint(1,100000,1000000)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['column'])
    scalar = np.random.randint(1,100000)
    df.column += scalar
    if df.column.max()==0:
        pdb()
```

My data variable gets full with zeros. Is it memory issues? If my data is smaller then this doesn't happen, but I need to process big data in a safe way!

```
>> print pandas.__version__
0.17.1
>> print numpy.__version__
1.10.1

Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Please post code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This happens with my own huge dataset that I can't transfer. I will try to make it work with some synthetic dataset. But as you can see the code is simple df['column']+scalar @FabioLamanna

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, for me it works fine and I obtain a dataframe with no-zero values. May you post your python, numpy, pandas versions?

Comment: Can people explain me why they are downvoting this? This is a serious issue..!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I'm guessing it's something on your computer/installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my version of `numexpr=2.4.4` updating to `numexpr=2.4.6` fixes the problem. Github issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12167